# Filter ListBox items based upon textbox from OnKeyUp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a ListBox containing a large number of items, which are all account numbers and so hard to search through.

Is it possible to have the items "filtered" as the user types into a textbox, so that only items that match what has been entered so far are displayed?

e.g.

> **List Box**
>   2342
>   3434
>   2332
>   3224

User then enters 3 in the texbox - onKeyUp the listbox is filtered to only display:

> **TextBox**
>   3
>
> **ListBox**
>   3434
>   3224

User then enters a 2 in the box:

> **Textbox**
>   32
>
> **ListBox**
>   3224

Is this possible in ASP.Net (not MVC2)?
If so, is it best via callback in an UpdatePanel or javascript of somekind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample solution

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      listBox1.Items.Clear();
      List<String> lst = new List<string> {"2342","3434","2332","3224"};
      listBox1.Items.AddRange(lst.Where(X => X.StartsWith(textBox1.Text)).ToArray());

  }
```

And one more

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(listBox1.Items.Cast<String>().Where(X=>X.StartsWith(textBox1.Text)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Needed to add as ListItems, but other than that a nice solution :)

Comment: In case if no text is entered to textbox, the listbox is empty, but should be filled with all existing entries in List lst.

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery implementation of this in [Jquery Listbox / Textbox filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688651/jquery-listbox-textbox-filter) which should get you started, even if you don't want to use jQuery.