# C# Filtering Listview by textbox

Tags: c#, listview

What I want is to type in a textbox before I start my packet sniffer to only show me results that I want. This is what I have but it isn't working. I want this listview to just show port 3074 using a textbox does anyone know how to do this? This is a packet sniffer

![The textbox where I want to choose what port][1]

http://gyazo.com/795fd2a8b55776653ae9b826fc8b6672

![This is where I just want it to show only one port not all][2]

http://gyazo.com/dbc30667495c5a26127f54754441e843

Anyone know how I can do that?

This is what I am using

```
for(int i=0;i< listView.Items.Count;i++)
{
if(listView.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text == "asdf")
{

}
```

}

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question.

Comment: There added what I tried. Honestly I am new to this.

Comment: @user3140279 This is the same question you asked before that was put on hold.  Edit the Original [*Post*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805966/showing-specific-port-when-packet-sniffing-and-hide-the-other-ones) instead of creating new ones please.

Comment: Ok! I'm sorry!!! Want me to edit that one now? And is this enough information @KSdev?

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like the [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16550441/2819245).

Comment: No? Why not? The example code given there answers your question precisely - filtering the listview according to some data/values. If that is not what you are looking for, please rephrase your question, so we get an understanding of what your problem is.

Comment: You need to read about `Sockets`.  Here are two links to get you on the path you need.
[*MSDN - Listening with Sockets*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz10xcwh(v=vs.110).aspx) AND/OR
[*C# Tutorial - Simple Threaded TCP Server*](http://tech.pro/tutorial/704/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server)

Comment: Ok, so I have a packet sniffer an open source one that don't have a filter feature now before I start sniffing I have where you select the ip and the port to show but it shows all on the listview and I don't want it to show all I just want it to show the port that I have specified in the textbox before I started sniffing. Do you have skype where you could help me or something?

Comment: @user3140279 If this `open source packet sniffer` you've obtained has a parameter for port this should be a very simple task that you can figure out on your own.  If this `open source` you've acquired does not have a parameter for port then you need to reference the two links I supplied in my previous comment.  You are going to have to put some effort forth in an attempt to resolve this issue on your own

Comment: This is the source: http://www.coderbag.com/Programming-C/Building-a-Network-Sniffer-in-NE

Answer (score 0):

Use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) -- an open source wrapper around a standard .NET ListView.

It does filtering and highlighting out of the box. See [this link for details](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#is-there-an-easy-way-to-only-show-rows-that-contain-some-text).

Highlighing in action:

[image]