# Dynamic search in C# ListView

Tags: c#, listview

I'm gonna' cut right to the chase here, and confess that I'm a bit of a newb at this stuff, so bear with me.

I have a list of `myObject`s. Each `myObject` has a few variables.

What I want to do is to be able to insert said object's variables into a `ListView`, and then be able to search through said variables with a basic `TextBox`. The results of this search will be the only entries in my `ListView` as the user types.

I fill my `ListView` like this:

```
ListView lv = new ListView();
lv.Columns.Add("FirstVariable");
lv.Columns.Add("SecondVariable");
lv.Columns.Add("ThirdVariable");
lv.View = View.Details;
lv.Width = 500;
lv.Height = 500;

foreach (var value in myListOfObjects)
{
    lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { value.key, value.title, value.typeName }));
}

//...
```

Now, I also have a `TextBox` in my `Form`, which I hope can be used to search through the rows of information in my `ListView` as the user types.

How would I go about doing this?

Can I use `EventHandler` on my `TextBox` to perhaps repopulate the `ListView` on each keypress or something?

If so, could anyone demonstrate how to do so?

Comment: something like [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/)? or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16550441/1841212)

Comment: @VisualBean I think you might have misslinked a little. That one just leads back here :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering items in a Listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549823/filtering-items-in-a-listview)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549823/filtering-items-in-a-listview/68043040#68043040 please take a look of my answer in the above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is;
On textbox_textChanged - remove all items from the listview and then add the ones that match an example could be;

> Warning - Sudo code incoming!

```
textbox_textChanged(Sender sender, SomeArgs args)
{
    lv.Clear();
    foreach(var item in originalCollection)
    {
        if(item.name.Contains(textbox.Text)
            lv.Add(item);
    }
}
```