# C#: Filtering listbox having List<String> as datasource

Tags: c#

I have a listbox that has a List assigned as datasource:

```
List<String> files = new List<String>();   
files.Add("test");   
files.Add("test2");   
ListBox1.DataSource = files;
```

Now the listbox shows me both entries of the List.

Is there a way to implement an easy filtering mechanism using a textbox?
So if i enter "2" into the textbox just the "test2" entry should be shown anymore.

Any suggestions?

Comment: take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688651/jquery-listbox-textbox-filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter List like this:

```
var filteredFiles = files.Where(x=>x.Contains(TextBox1.Text));
```

and than assign filteredFiles as DataSource

Hope this helps.

Edit:
Try this:

```
 var filteredFiles = files.Where(x=>x.Contains(TextBox1.Text)).ToArray();
```

or

```
 var filteredFiles = files.Where(x=>x.Contains(TextBox1.Text)).ToList();
```

Sorry, it has been a while since I did a databinding in asp.net :D

Comment: thx for you help but this is not working: "the complex databinding accepts as a datasource either an Ilist or an IListSource"

Comment: so is it correct if i use this like this:        private void tbxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbxSongs.DataSource = files.Where(x => x.Contains(tbxSearch.Text)).ToArray();
}

Comment: Yo better attach this code to some other event. Add a Button and put this code in it's click event.

Comment: I need the filter to be applied everytime the user changes the text in my textbox. Do i really have to set the datasource each time completely new?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = files.Where(item => item.Contains(textBox.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption that you want to do this on the client side, not just filter the List object with C#.  If that's the case, you can use a jQuery plugin to help.  Check out the Filtered List plugin:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/FilteredList

See a demo here:  http://emi.github.com/filtered_list/#long-static-list